# Buscar resultados em uma tabela de conversas privadas

Tags: php, mysql

gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês pois não consegui fazer com os tópicos que encontrei na internet.

Eu tenho uma tabela de "Chat" com os seguintes campos:
[image: Estrutura da tabela Chat]

E estou utilizando o seguinte select:

```
SELECT b.`id`, b.`Fullname`, b.`Photo`, a.`Message`
FROM `Chat` AS a
INNER JOIN `Users` AS b ON b.`id` = a.`SenderBy`
WHERE a.`ReceiverBy` = '2'
GROUP BY a.`SenderBy`
ORDER BY a.`CreateDate`
LIMIT 20
```

Que me retorna o seguinte resultado:
[image: resultado da query acima]

Mas o esperado deveria ser:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enfim, o que eu estava tendo fazer:
Selecionar em ordem decrescente as últimas mensagens recebidas por grupo de SenderBy.

Comment: Tenta alterar de `ORDER BY a.CreateDate` por  `ORDER BY a.CreateDate DESC`

Comment: Não funcionou como o esperando também, só mudou que o Lucas Soares ficou em primeiro, o que está errado.